# How to Re-Execute Log4j "Default Initialization Procedure"?

Tags: java, configuration, log4j, default, reset

At runtime I often create/modify **log4j** Loggers, Appenders, Levels, Layouts, and time to time need to reset everything back to defaults.

**Log4j** system has well defined **[Default Initialization Procedure](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit)** that is executed when **log4j** classes are loaded into memory. Is there any way to re-execute the entire Procedure programmatically later at runtime?

I found several `resetConfiguration()` methods in **log4j** documentation, but not sure if any of them will do what the **[Default Initialization Procedure](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit)** does:

- `BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration();`
- `Hierarchy.resetConfiguration();`
- `LogManager.resetConfiguration();`

Any other suggestions on resetting **log4j** configurations are more then welcome! Thank you.

Comment: I suppose configureandwatch doesn't suit your needs (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.6)

Comment: No "configureandwatch" doesn't help, because the configuration files don't change. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html) for the `doConfigure` method:

Read configuration from a file. **The existing configuration is not cleared nor reset**. If you require a different behavior, then **call `resetConfiguration` method before calling doConfigure**.

So I belive that calling `LogManager.resetConfiguration()` and recall `PropertyConfigurator.configure()` with the same files as on startup will do what you want.

The `resetConfiguration()` method is documented in [Hierarchy](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/jakarta-log4j-1.2.8/src/java/org/apache/log4j/Hierarchy.java.shtml) class.

Comment: It worked to me, thanks! And it also works without calling LogManager.resetConfiguration(), just PropertyConfigurator.configure(URL configURL)

Comment: If you don't call LogManager.resetConfiguration() there can be stale config from the previous version of the log4j.properties. e.g. Levels on loggers that are no longer specified in the new version.

Comment: How to do it in log4j 2.12

Answer (score 7):

This question is related to [skiphoppy's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12162423/1082681) which I answered earlier today. The bounty question he added to this one here calls for a more tricky solution than Jan Zyka's:

Because the default initialisation is a hard-coded static block executed only once during class-loading of `LogManager`, you need AOP (aspect-oriented programming), more specifically AspectJ in order to intercept the static initialiser. I explained how to do that in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206797/1082681) to skiphoppy's other question.

Okay, so now we can intercept the static initialisation and trick LogManager into telling us the URL, but in order to re-execute the whole code block we need another trick called a **worker object pattern**. Here is the sample code, the explanation follows:

**Sample application class:**

```java
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4jDemo {
    public static Runnable log4jDefaultInitCmd;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("scrum-master.de");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        logger.info("Hello world!");
        logger.info("Now sleeping for 2 sec...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        logger.info("I am awake again!");
        if (log4jDefaultInitCmd != null) {
            logger.info("Re-running log4j default initialisation");
            log4jDefaultInitCmd.run();
        }
        logger.info("Done");
    }
}
```

**Aspect intercepting static initialisation of `LogManager`:**

```java
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;

public aspect Log4jAspect {
    Object around() : staticinitialization(LogManager) {
        System.out.println("log4j static initialisation");
        Log4jDemo.log4jDefaultInitCmd = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                proceed();
            }
        };
        Log4jDemo.log4jDefaultInitCmd.run();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**How it works:**

It is beyond the scope of this answer to explain the general concept of AOP, so I assume you know it or are going to read something in order to understand it.

- `Log4jAspect` intercepts `LogManager`'s static initialisation in an `around()` advice.
- Within the advice, the `proceed()` call (i.e. the execution of the static initialisation) is packaged inside a worker object implemented by an anonymous `Runnable` instance. This effectively wraps the call into an object with a `run()` method which can be issued at will. (Aha, here is our trick! In more dynamic languages like Scala you would call this a lexical scope.)
- After wrapping the static initialisation, we assign the `Runnable` instance to another class's public static member so it becomes accessible outside the aspect.
- Still inside the advice, we proceed with the static initialisation by calling the worker object's `run()` method.

So far, so good, now the `LogManager` class has been loaded and initialised properly, just as if no aspect did exist. But now look at `Log4jDemo.main`:

- We initialise the logger and log some events.
- We wait for 2 seconds (just enough time to check the console output for what has happened so far).
- We continue and **re-issue the default initialisation** by calling once more the worker object's `run()` method.

If you use command line argument `-Dlog4j.debug=true`, you will see something like this:

```
log4j static initialisation
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@17182c1.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@17182c1 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@17182c1.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/Robin/Eigene%20Dateien/java-src/dummy2/bin/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/C:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/Robin/Eigene%20Dateien/java-src/dummy2/bin/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[debug, stdout].
log4j: Level token is [debug].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
12:41:22,647  INFO de:13 - Hello world!
0 [main] INFO scrum-master.de  - Hello world!
12:41:22,663  INFO de:14 - Now sleeping for 2 sec...
16 [main] INFO scrum-master.de  - Now sleeping for 2 sec...
12:41:24,663  INFO de:16 - I am awake again!
2016 [main] INFO scrum-master.de  - I am awake again!
12:41:24,663  INFO de:18 - Re-running log4j default initialisation
2016 [main] INFO scrum-master.de  - Re-running log4j default initialisation
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@17182c1.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@17182c1 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@17182c1.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/Robin/Eigene%20Dateien/java-src/dummy2/bin/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/C:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/Robin/Eigene%20Dateien/java-src/dummy2/bin/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[debug, stdout].
log4j: Level token is [debug].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
12:41:24,663  INFO de:21 - Done
2016 [main] INFO scrum-master.de  - Done
```

**Tadaa!** As you can see, the default initialisation has indeed been executed twice. The log output proves it. For example you see `Using URL [file:/(...)]` twice in the log.

**Conclusion:**

While this is not a particularly nice way to re-issue log4j default initialisation compared to the more desireable situation that it not be hard-coded but exposed to the user via an API call, the facts are as they are and we need this trick. I do doubt that it should be necessary to re-run the full default initialisation block in any given situation, but because the question was asked, I wanted to answer it precisely and not by suggesting a workaround. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Jan Zyka's solution pointed me in the right direction, but I'm using an XML configuration file rather than a properties files. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
    LogManager.resetConfiguration(); // clear any existing config first
    LoggerRepository loggerRepository = LogManager.getLoggerRepository();
    DOMConfigurator domConfigurator = new DOMConfigurator();
    try (
        InputStream is = MyClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/log4j.xml");
    ) {
        domConfigurator.doConfigure(is, loggerRepository);
    }
    LOGGER.info("abc123");
```

I get a properly formatted log4j log entry with "abc123" as the log message.