# How can you combine log4j default initialization with configureAndWatch()?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Some **Log4j** Configurators have a `configureAndWatch()` method, that *starts a Thread* to watch the file used for configuration (`XML` file or `properties` file) and *trigger* a reconfigure if the file *changes*.

However, if you rely on the `Log4j` *default initialization* procedure, you never get a chance to call `configureAndWatch()`.  You don't even know the file that was used to configure with (it might not even be a file.)

Is there a good way to get *`configureAndWatch()`* style behavior, allowing changing of the log configuration on the fly, while still using the *default initialization* procedure?  I am assuming that your configuration URL ultimately resolves to a file that can be watched, as a URL on another server would probably not be something you would want to pull every *60 seconds*.

(I see that the `configureAndWatch()` method is not safe in a *Java EE*  environment because of the separate thread, and I see that some app servers have their own mechanism for watching the `log4j` configuration file, but the program I am working on at the moment is not running in *Java EE* .)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've scrapped everything in the answer before and started over now that I better understand what you want.

The following paragraph describes the real sequence that log4j uses to determine what the log4j config file name is. This code tries to follow those rules.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit

It determines what log4j configuration file to use and then sets up the PropertyConfigurator using the file it found. This will only work if the file is located on the file system. It will not work if the file is inside a jar or at a remote HTTP URL.

```
    String prop = System.getProperty("log4j.configuration");
    if (prop == null) prop = "log4j.properties";
    URL log4jConfig = Loader.getResource(prop);
    if (log4jConfig.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("file")) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(log4jConfig.getFile().substring(1), 10000);
    }
    else {
        // cannot monitor if file changed because URL is not a file
    }
```

Comment: Given the current constraints of log4j, I think this solution is the best possible.  The only problem I see is that if you are getting the properties yourself, there is a chance you'll miss checking exactly all the same things that log4j checks in default initialization.

Comment: **important**: Don't use the substring(1) on linux, cause that'll screw up the path.

Comment: I had to remove substring(1) also on Windows running on OSX, as the path to the file begins with \\psf (mounted from the OSX file system)

Comment: configureAndWatch creates new thread and not ideal for jee system

Answer (score 2):

> However, if you rely on the Log4j ***default initialization procedure***, you never get a chance to call configureAndWatch(). You don't even know the file that was used to configure with (it might not even be a file.)

You have posted some related questions which I have already answered in [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206797/1082681) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12213782/1082681), so this answer is building upon the explanations of the others. Again, I am using AspectJ:

**Sample application class:**

```java
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4jDemo {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("scrum-master.de");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            logger.info("Log message");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

**Aspect capturing the default URL and handing it over to `configureAndWatch`:**

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;

public aspect Log4jAspect {
    after(URL defaultURL) returning :
        within(LogManager) &&
        cflow(staticinitialization(LogManager)) &&
        call(* OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(URL, ..)) &&
        args(defaultURL, ..)
    {
        try {
            PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(new File(defaultURL.toURI()).getAbsolutePath(), 2000);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new SoftException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it with `-Dlog4j.configDebug=true` from Eclipse, changing the output channel back and forth from `System.log` (black colour in Eclipse console) to `System.err` (red colour, here not visible) in *log4j.properties*, and it worked nicely. In the log output you also see the debug info for reconfiguration after a detected file change:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@f4a24a.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@f4a24a class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@f4a24a.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/Robin/Eigene%20Dateien/java-src/dummy2/bin/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/C:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/Robin/Eigene%20Dateien/java-src/dummy2/bin/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[debug, stdout].
log4j: Level token is [debug].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.err].
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[debug, stdout].
log4j: Level token is [debug].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.err].
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
17:48:20,944  INFO de:10 - Log message
17:48:22,944  INFO de:10 - Log message
17:48:24,944  INFO de:10 - Log message
17:48:26,944  INFO de:10 - Log message
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[debug, stdout].
log4j: Level token is [debug].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
17:48:28,944  INFO de:10 - Log message
17:48:30,944  INFO de:10 - Log message
17:48:32,944  INFO de:10 - Log message
17:48:34,944  INFO de:10 - Log message
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[debug, stdout].
log4j: Level token is [debug].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.err].
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
17:48:36,944  INFO de:10 - Log message
17:48:38,944  INFO de:10 - Log message
```

Comment: Thank guy, i also have this idea to modify the current logging system without changing code, i used Spring AOP instead.

Comment: Then you must have done it in another way because Spring AOP neither supports `cflow()` nor `call()`. So how did you implement your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before using the default logger and appenders. You will have to write a separate handler for watching property file modifications. When a change occurs just reset your logger and re-add the appender settings:

```
/**
 * Setup log4j appender.
 */
public static void setupLog4jAppender(Class appender) {
    getLogger();

    String rootLogger=(String)props.get("log4j.rootLogger");
    rootLogger+=",appname";
    getProps().setProperty("log4j.rootLogger", rootLogger);

    getProps().put("log4j.appender.appname", appender.getName());  // Our custom appender
    getProps().put("log4j.appender.appname.layout", "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"); 
    //See: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/docs/api/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html
    getProps().put("log4j.appender.appname.layout.ConversionPattern", "%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n");

    LogManager.resetConfiguration();
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(getProps());
}
```