# How can you find what URL was used in log4j default initialization?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

[Log4j default initialization](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit) goes through a procedure to find and use a URL to configure with.  Afterward, how can you find out what URL was ultimately used, without having to code the same procedure yourself?  (If you have to code it yourself, you might not get it exactly the same as log4j does, and also it might change in a future release.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to use AspectJ LTW (load-time weaving), you can take a look at the static initialisation of `LogManager` mentioned by Ian Roberts. In *log4j 1.2.14* it looks like this:

```java
static {
    // (...)
    // if there is no default init override, then get the resource
    // specified by the user or the default config file.
    if (override == null || "false".equalsIgnoreCase(override)) {
        // (...)
        URL url = null;

        // (...)    
        // If we have a non-null url, then delegate the rest of the
        // configuration to the OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure method.
        if (url != null) {
            LogLog.debug("Using URL [" + url + "] for automatic log4j configuration.");
            OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(
                url, configuratorClassName, LogManager.getLoggerRepository()
            );
        } else {
            LogLog.debug("Could not find resource: [" + configurationOptionStr + "].");
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously if a default URL could be determined then `OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(URL, ..)` will be called at one point within the static block in order to initialise *log4j* with that URL.

By means of *AspectJ* it is pretty simple to catch that method invocation:

```java
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;

public aspect Log4jAspect {
    before(URL defaultURL) :
        within(LogManager) &&
        cflow(staticinitialization(LogManager)) &&
        call(* OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(URL, ..)) &&
        args(defaultURL, ..)
    {
        System.out.println("log4j default URL = " + defaultURL);
    }
}
```

In prose this code means:

- If we are within class LogManager and
- within the control flow of the static class initialisation and
- `OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure`is called,
- then capture the first argument (the URL) and
- print it to the console (you could just as well do something else).

If there is no default URL, nothing will be printed. Instead of printing the URL you could assign it to a static member of any class or whatever you like.

This is a solution for your problem, I tested it and it works. I would be happy to receive the bounty for answering your question, even though maybe the solution uses a technology you did not have in mind. But it solves the problem. :-)

---

**Edit:** It is also possible to explicitly intercept the log call in the case that no default URL is found, even though I do not think it is necessary. I just wanted to mention it.

Comment: Your answers are fantastically informative.  Thank you.  A great way to approach something that apparently can't be done exactly the way I would like to.

Comment: >1000 rep a day. impressive :P

Answer (score 4):

The procedure used is hard-coded in a static initializer block in `LogManager`, so there doesn't appear to be a way to hook into it.  The only place where it tells you what's going on is

```
LogLog.debug("Using URL ["+url+"] for automatic log4j configuration.");
```

but `LogLog` itself is hard-coded to use `System.out.println` for these messages so the only possibility I can see is to switch on debugging (`-Dlog4j.debug=true`) and somehow hook in to `System.setOut` before log4j is initialized, then parse the debug log message.  But that is probably even more fragile than coding the config procedure yourself.

Even then, there may have been other programmatic configuration applied after the default configuration procedure (e.g. a Spring `Log4jConfigListener`) - there isn't necessarily a single configuration URL as such.

It might be worth putting in a log4j feature request to factor out the config file search code into a static method that you can call from elsewhere, but that wouldn't help when you might have to cope with earlier versions of log4j.

Answer (score 4):

If you can setup your own Configurator you can do something like that:

Setup the JAVA system property : -Dlog4j.configuratorClass=MyConfigurator
And then have your configurator instance intercepts the doConfigure call.

```
public class MyConfigurator implements Configurator
{
    public static URL url;

    @Override
    public void doConfigure(URL url, LoggerRepository repository)
    {
        this.url = url;
        new PropertyConfigurator().doConfigure(url, repository);
    }
}
```

Comment: This suggests another clever idea: overriding the Configurator by inserting your own earlier on the classpath...

Answer (score 1):

Insert this into your java call:

```
-Dlog4j.configDebug=true
```

Thats all.

Comment: I'm looking for a way for my program to find this information.